# Compute limit of integral

Tags: measure-theory

I'm having trouble with the following question:

Compute $ \lim \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)$ where $f_n(x) = \frac{n x \log x}{1 + n^2 x^2}$

Could I have a hint please?

Thank you!

Comment: Try the dominated convergence theorem.  Note that $y/(1+y^2) \leq 1/2$ for all $y \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but $\log x$ isn't integrable on $(0,1)$, so how would you dominate the function?

Comment: $\log x$ is certainly integrable on $(0,1)$.

Comment: whoops sorry!! Makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the dominated convergence theorem. Note that $y/(1+y^2) \leq 1/2$ for all $y \geq 0$.